# InDesign Faux Italic Font for EPUB

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, css, epub

I'm producing an EPUB with Adobe InDesign.

Most of the fonts I'm using have Italic and Bold versions.  I simply select the correct font in InDesign, and it is set up as a `@font-face` in the CSS when I export to EPUB.  So that works fine.

However, I have one font that I need to make Italic, but there is no Italic version of that font.  In normal CSS, I could simply say `font-style:italic` and be done with it.  But there is no way to set that in InDesign, since it operates with fonts normally.  I can apply a skew to the letters, but I don't think that would translate how I'd like into CSS.

Is there a way to set a character style in InDesign so that it will use my font, but set `font-style:italic` in the resultant CSS?

Comment: Not that I know of! Like you said, I normally just do approx. 11º skew depending on the font. I'll be interested to see if there is a better workaround. Good question @MattMc!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few years old, but this might be helpful for someone else...

```
.fauxitalic {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skewx(-11deg);
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rc9se1yd/